# One word for "important matters"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word to fit in a phrase such as

> I sent him a letter about the **important matters** in my life.

or

> I love to speak with my friend concerning **important matters** in our lives.

I am looking for something like an antonym to **minutiae**. The only one I found was **generality**, but that does not confer the idea of importance. **Milestone** is not a bad word, but it more denotes an important event on a timeline.

Is there any such word in English?

Comment: I understand that you want a word to pair with "life" but more context would be helpful. Exactly what are these "important matters"? Question seems a bit open-ended.

Comment: **Concern** means matter of importance. Or [**essentials**](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=essentials+antonym&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=1LGqVYvRI9iDuATZ-ZzoCw#q=essentials+antonym&nirf=essentials+synonyms).

Comment: @Jimmy Well the phrasing would be a little odd if I were to use "concerns" in that second sentence (...concerning concerns...), but I like that word. I think it works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but **vicissitudes** conveys the meaning you want in those sentences.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. The connotation is a bit too negative I think. But +1 for a good word. It will work for me in some situations.

Comment: Also, welcome to English stackexchange

Comment: I had always heard it as a neutral word, but after investigating further it seems it does usually have a negative connotation. And thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd not use a single word here myself, but perhaps the best fit would be **imperatives**.

> *imperative* noun 1 An essential or urgent thing ...

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imperative).

> 'Working with the students led me to understand some of the
>   imperatives of life that impact their ability to live up to
>   expectations.'

{[What Makes Students Tick? _ Udoh Elijah Udom](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EsSqBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22imperatives+of+life%22&source=bl&ots=K5cbD1Vo6L&sig=sAJcOnOXwSqsdiMrlb96J8LouTw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgKahUKEwjBsdqh4NjGAhXMB9sKHYbNBd0#v=onepage&q=%22imperatives%20of%20life%22&f=false)}

Comment: +1 First word came into my mind when I saw the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Try **[essentials](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essential)**: as a count noun, *essential* means

> something that is basic or necessary : something essential

Answer (score 0):

What *kind* of

> "important matters" in life

are you referring to?

1. goals/achievements/things to be done? try **objectives**
2. similar to 1. but deciding on which one is *more* important? try **priorities**
3. way of life/morals/deciding on what is meaningful? try **values** or **conscience**

Your question looks for a general word but example sentences involve "life" so I suggested a few that will give better meaning in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

OP can use the *noun* **consequence** to indicate importance or relevance, e.g., matters of *consequence*.

**1**. I sent him a letter about matters of (*some*) consequence in my life.

**2**. I love to speak with my friend concerning matters of (*great*) consequence in 
our lives.

> [**consequence**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consequence)
>   *noun*:
>
> **3a**: importance with respect to power to produce an effect. “a mistake of no *consequence*”
>
> **3b**: social importance (Merriam-Webster *online*)